# How can I access the mongodb scalingo database?

Tags: mongodb

How can I access the mongodb scalingo database and be able to see the records that I have and be able to edit it, and add data directly to my application?

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is to use the Scalingo command line to get a `mongo` console. [1](https://doc.scalingo.com/platform/databases/access)

If you want to use a desktop client with a graphical interface like Robo3T, there is a guide for this. [2](https://doc.scalingo.com/addons/scalingo-mongodb/robo3t)

The last option is to open your database on the Internet after enforcing secured access with TLS. [3](https://doc.scalingo.com/addons/scalingo-mongodb/start#remote-access-your-database)

Regards,

Comment: I do not understand this I was using what they indicate use robot 3t I do all the step indicated by the guide but when configuring with adrress 127.0.0.1: 10000 I get this error

enter image description here

What confuses me is the password authetication part exactly how do I get it right? since I add the one that I get when applying according to the example of the guide scalingo --app my-app env | grep MONGO_URL but do not be that correct

and using robomongo when I do the test test comes out this

enter image description here

Hope you can help me!

Comment: Have your forced TLS with your database? In this case you need to configure the SSL tab of robo 3T also. If you don't need force TLS, disable it and robo 3T will be able to connect just with the guide you've followed